# Joining two datasets in one report

Tags: mysql, sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I have 2 (two) datasets and I want to joining it together.

The 1st is a `mysql` query and 2nd is a `mssql` query, I have set a parameter which is the `userid` from the `mysql` query and added this to my `mssql` query.

If I execute the `mssql` query and add the parameter my self then the report will run.

I want to be able to set the `mssql` query to pull the `userid` from the `mysql` query and then output the information in another table. Is this possible? or is there another way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SSRS is not designed to join datasets together, so anything you do figure out will be a workaround. Can you explain more about how you're using the parameter to make it work going from mySQL to msSQL?

Also, if this is data you'll be accessing and working with regularly, you may consider joining the resultsets on the database end. For instance, you can create a view in the msSQL database that contains a Linked Server Protocol to the other database, and integrate the data within the view, and reference the view through your report.

Hope this helps.